# LPC1768 internal RTC time register is not incrementing

Tags: microcontroller, nxp, lpc1768

Value is read right,but time is not incrementing.

```
 int main()
    {
        uint16_t year,hour, min, sec, date, month;  



    uart_init(9600);


    LPC_RTC->CCR  =   0x00;    //Disable RTC


    LPC_RTC->DOM    = 17;   
    LPC_RTC->MONTH  = 02;  
    LPC_RTC->YEAR   = 2019;


    LPC_RTC->HOUR   = 05;   
    LPC_RTC->MIN    = 50;   
    LPC_RTC->SEC    = 00;   

    LPC_RTC->CCR  =   0x01;    //Enable RTC


    while (1)
    {
        /* Read Time */
        hour = LPC_RTC->HOUR;
        min  = LPC_RTC->MIN; 
        sec  = LPC_RTC->SEC; 

        /* Read Date */
        date  = LPC_RTC->DOM;   
        month = LPC_RTC->MONTH;  
        year  = LPC_RTC->YEAR;   

        /* Display date and time on Serial window */

                uart_string("\r\nDate: ");
                uart_integer(date);
                uart_tx('-');
                uart_integer(month);
                uart_tx('-');
                uart_integer(year);

                uart_string("\r\nTime: ");
                uart_integer(hour);
                uart_tx(':');
                uart_integer(min);
                uart_tx(':');
                uart_integer(sec);
                uart_string("\r\n\r\n");

    }   
}
```

Comment: Is the clock source for the RTC configured correctly?

Comment: There is no clock source selection option in Clock Control Register.

Comment: You didn't reset the RTC module. Write 1 to Calibration enable bit and Reset bit. Then Reset Calibration register value and in next instructions, enable RTC as you did.

Comment: I wrote like this....  `LPC_RTC->CCR=0x12;
LPC_RTC->CALIBRATION = 0x00;.........LPC_RTC->CCR=0x01;`  Still not working.

Comment: @Swanand I checked oscillator status using "RTC Oscillator Fail detect flag"  in RTC Auxiliary control register & it shows oscillator failed.